# Is there any way to generate a uniform distribution out of two other distributions which are uniform?

Tags: random

X=rand(n,1) is a random variable which is uniformly distributed and the range of X is between 0 to 1. I want variable Y to be negatively correlated with X with corrcoef equal to -0.4 and its distribution be uniform and range of Y be between 0 to 1.
I tackle this problem in this way that I introduced a noise to the problem "z" such that: Y=\alpha(1-X)+\beta(z) and z=rand(n,1)

\alpha here is 0.4 and \beta is 0.6. The corrcoef(X,Y) is around -0.4 and the range of Y is [0 1] which satisfy our condition but the distribution of Y is not uniform any more. IT IS NORMAL. How can I satisfy this condition as well?

I expexct the summation of two uniform distribution be uniform as well but it is normal.

Comment: Your intuition is wrong. The [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) says that sums of random variables (with some constraints) converge to normality as the number of terms increases. If you start with normals, the convergence is a *fait accompli* and the sum is normal. If you start with uniforms, adding two yields a triangle distribution. As you add more it starts to look more and more normal. But sums of uniforms are definitely not uniform. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) for more info.

Comment: My problem is not whether it is normal or a triangle. My problem is I want uniform distribution after introducing noise.

Comment: And I'm telling you that you won't get a uniform from adding uniforms.

Comment: How should I solve my problem? I need Y to be uniform and negatively correlated with X. how should I resolve it?

Comment: You could always start by doing some research. Somebody might have [solved this problem before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66610/generate-pairs-of-random-numbers-uniformly-distributed-and-correlated).